# socialite/laravel moving models broke the google login

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-socialite

I moved all my laravel's Model into App\Model;
I edit all config file for making User model working and all is ok, all my model now have:

```
namespace App\Model;
```

on top of the class.

Ive even a Model for SocialLite package, when i try to login via google the autoloader rise this error:
[image: social lite class error]

What can I edit to make it works again?
thanks

Comment: Can you send error codes in text instead of image url?

Comment: OK I see your pic.  Then what do yo do in your `SocialGoogleAccountService`? Do you share it?

Comment: i was totally miss this file! you point me in the right direction many thanks! u can put it as solution: "edit the namespace for the class "SocialGoogleAccountService"

Comment: I am glad to solve your problem. Good luck :)